# How to write a feign client for an api that has multiple identically named query params?

Tags: java, spring-boot, openfeign

I am trying to write a feign client to make calls to retrieve data from a server where the api accepts a list of identical named query parameters to determine how much data is being asked. Here is an example url I am trying to hit:

```
http://some-server/some-endpoint/{id}?include=profile&include=account&include=address&include=email
```

So far for my feign client I'm attempting to set it up this way:

```
@FeignClient("some-server")
public interface SomeServerClient {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,
      value = "/customers/api/customers/{id}",
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
  Map<Object, Object> queryById(
      @PathVariable long id,
      @RequestParam("include[]") String ... include);

  default Map<Object, Object> queryById(long id) {
    return queryById(id,"profile", "account", "address", "email");
  }
```

However this doesn't appear t format the request in the way desired, so my question is how can I set up my feign client to submit its request to the url as shown in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `@RequestParam("include") List<String> includes`, example:

*client*:

```java
@FeignClient(value = "foo-client")
public interface FooClient {

    @GetMapping("/foo")
    Foo getFoo(@RequestParam("include") List<String> includes);

}
```

*controller*:

```java
@RestController
public class FooController {

    @GetMapping("/foo")
    public Foo getFoo(@RequestParam("include") List<String> includes) {
        return new Foo(includes);
    }

}
```

*usage*:

```java
List<String> includes = new ArrayList<>();
        includes.add("foo");
        includes.add("bar");

        Foo foo = fooClient.getFoo(includes);
```

*url*:

```
http://some-server/foo?include=foo&include=bar
```